# Are these CW-complexes homotopy dominated by each other?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $K_i$ for $i$ a prime, be the 2-dimensional CW-complex with a single vertex associated with the presentation $$\mathcal{P}_i=\langle r,s,t\; |\; s^2 =t^3, [r^2 ,s^{2i+1}]=1,[r^2 ,t^{3i+1}]=1\rangle .$$

M. Lustig [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002240499390021K) has shown that the $K_i$ have isomorphic fundamental groups and pairwise different homotopy types.

My question: For $i\neq j$, are $K_i$ and $K_j$ homotopy dominated by each other?

Recall that a topological space $Y$ is *homotopy dominated* by a topological space $X$ if there are maps $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ such that $fg\simeq \mathrm{id}_Y$.

Comment: Do you know if the homotopy-invariant used in the paper is also a domination invariant?  Which invariant do they use?

Comment: Dear @RyanBudney , thanks for the comment. I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean fundamental group and Euler characteristic as homotopy-invariants?

Comment: @RyanBudney They are distinguished by $H_2$ with coefficients in $\Bbb Z [\pi_1]/(g)$, where g is a generator of (probably fully?) characteristic subgroup; you can then fiddle a bit and show that they are equal to $\pi_2 \oplus$ non-isomorphic rank 1 summands, but construction is, as I said, fiddly, and I'm not sure that decomposition is well-defined up to homotopy idempotents (rather than autoequivalences); and those rank 1 modules are (as far as I remember) stably equivalent.

Comment: @M.Ramana: Denis T answered my question, thanks.

Comment: @RyanBudney Sure.